# click image map and open modal window in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, imagemap

Good afternoon. I have an image map and need to open a modal clicking on the image.
However, I found out today that I can not use the tags   to image map ...
I wonder how can I open a modal using image-map

It does not work like this:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/myApp/test"/>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal"><area shape="rect" coords="289,399,368,662 ></a>
```

To run the map would have to be without the tags "a href" as below ...

```
<area shape="rect" coords="289,399,368,662" href="<c:url value="/myApp/test"/>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">
```

only in this way does not open modal bootstrapping.

Comment: is it just a image or map ?
You just want to open a model box on clicking ?

Comment: @HabibRehman I managed doing the slicing images with Fireworks program,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and encounter this solution.
We should remove the href from area and include the data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#id"

```
 <img src="desktop.jpg usemap="#May2May16-1">
  <map name="May2May16-1" class="default">
    <area shape="rect" coords="691,336,1239,375" style="outline:none" title="Offer Details" alt="Offer Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    </map>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```